# Can I Use post increment in function return in C?

Tags: c, function, return, post-increment

can I use post-increment in a function return in C like this?

```
int meta_solve() {    
  //some codes
  return metaData[head++]; //head is global variable
}
```

I asking this question because it showing the different results on windows and mac. thanks for your attention. have a great day!

Comment: It depends on how you're calling the function. If you're calling the function twice with no sequence point between them, the order that they're called is not specified, so the order of the increments will change.

Comment: Post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're seeing.

Comment: What is `head`? What is `metaData[]` ?

Comment: @Barmar While that is true, it doesn't change that post-increment in the return statement is fine.

Comment: not a windows or mac thing but one compiler from another, show the dissassembly from each one you think varies

Comment: @4386427 Right, it would be just as much of a problem if the increment were in its own statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will work.

The return will not happen until the expression `metaData[head++]` is fully evaluated so the (global) variable `head` is incremented before the function returns.

Comment: Actually, it is a defect in the C standard that nothing in the normative text states there is a sequence point after a `return` statement. Theoretically, the increment is allowed to happen after the function returns. If the call is inside a larger expression , the increment may not be sequenced with respect to other things in the expression.